# SQL Server Agent Proxies

Tags: sql-server, ssis, agent

I have just created an SSIS package and was able to hook it up to a SQL Server Agent Job.  In the tutorial, it showed me to create a Proxies account.  What exactly is a proxies account?

Answer (score 0):

In many job step types you can specify "Run as..." accounts (or proxies, or credentials) to execute this specific job step.
You need this, for example, if your SQL Server Agent service is running under Local System account, but you wish to run your SSIS Package under particular domain user (to access file shares, remote servers and so on - actually there are a lot of cases there you need different logins to run your tasks).
So, you create (provide) Credentials (login and password) of this user (SQL Server encrypts and store them for future uses - so you should provide them just once), and then create so called "proxy", assigning this credentials to different types of tasks. Then you just use them in the "Run as..." fields.

Other practice (I think not good, but could be used too) is to simply run SQL Agent Service under elevated account. Even domain admin, if you domain just local, or very secured. If you do so - you'll need proxy only in the very specific cases...

So the proxy - is the feature to enhance (or maintain) security of your environment.

One more case there you may need different logins for your ssis packages is the Resource Governor feature. For instance: 4 databases, 4 ETL cycles (many jobs'n'steps) for each database, and a 4 proxy accounts (logins) for each ETL cycle assigned to them tasks. Then you can assign Workload group for each login and divide your server resources between them as you wish. And you'll see in the SSISsyslog the execution account for each of your packages, so you should be able to determine easily that do you need to do in case of any problems.

Hope this helps :)